# Disabling mysql autocommit in php does not work

Tags: php, mysql, autocommit

Ofcourse I might be doing something wrong, but I don't really understand why and how.

I want to disable autocommit in php script. this because my personal php mysql framework works that way. yet somehow autocommit cannot be turned off. I'm using Mysqli with engine=InnoDB tables and i tried the mysqli::autocommit functionality as well as the mysql statements for global and session.

everything results in the same answer: autocommit is still on. No errors saying I used incorrect statement is returned. the queries returns true, tried committing, returned true.

is there anything i'm missing here? autocommit has to be turned off runtime because the host it will be running on does not allow me to disable it in the server settings :)

Comment: Worked for me in some situation - can you share any code for this? How do you setup/start the transactions? How do you ensure that you're actually in a transaction before you run commands?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `start transaction;` query?

Comment: well, currently i have autocommit off, it says autocommit value is 0. but even then any insert queries are being committed somehow.

@pageid, all i do is turn off autocommit, run the insert query, and then run a savepoint function which actually runs my save($commit=false) function which will do the insert, but not the commit. the weird thing is, save is the only function using mysqli_commit...

Comment: well, i've tried the start transaction, in navicat that works as expected, in PHP not...it still commits, while autocommit is off and start transaction is being run..

Comment: Somehow a rollback has to be called, now my problem lies in when do i execute? since in the __destruct function of php the variable containing the connection is being destroyed...

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_autocommit

By default, client connections begin with `autocommit` set to 1. To cause clients to begin with a default of 0, set the server's `init_connect` system variable:

```
SET GLOBAL init_connect='SET autocommit=0';
```

The `init_connect` variable can also be set on the command line or in an option file. To set the variable as just shown using an option file, include these lines:

```
[mysqld]
init_connect='SET autocommit=0'
```

Also view the following [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php), there is a way to return a boolean which will indicate whether commit was successfully turned on/off.

Also use `@@autocommit` to determine the current state of autocommit.

Comment: Well, autocommit is off, i realised that I was stupid and did not fetch the query result ;). but any insert queries are being committed while i'm definitely jus run the insert query, and never mysqli_commit. I also tried your init_connect suggestion, but it did not work!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to you all, I've solved my problem! I somehow figured out that when you do not explicitly do a rollback or close your connection, the inserts are committed. with register_shutdown_function you can do a rollback or close a connection.

again, thank you for your help!

Comment: Don't forget to set your answer as accepted, or edit our quesion and mark the person that helped get you on the right path as the accepted answer.